# How to test nested function in jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

can we test nested function in jasmine? its giving an error as "Cannot read property 'inner' of undefined". Please look into the following,

My test file is,

```
describe('sample.js', function(){
        it('test', function(){
            expect(outer()).toBe(true);
            expect(inner()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

And java script file is,

```
 function outer(){
        function inner(){
            return true;
        };
        return true;
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't test nested functions - as they're private inside the father function.

The solution would be to move it outside of the nested function. Such as:

`function outer() { return true; }
function inner() { return true; }`

Comment: True. But one should not export private/inner functions just for testing. If some function is private (for a reason) only the overall outcome of a public function is of interest and should be tested.